# Grammaire dans la phrase « il aurait dû avoir pitié »

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, conditionnel

Dans la phrase ci-dessous, comment expliquer la grammaire? Il y a le futur et le participe passé dans la même phrase. Je n'ai jamais vu ça.

> Il aurait dû avoir pitié.

Pouvez-vous m'expliquer s'il vous plaît?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cette phrase utilise le conditionnel passé. Lisez cet article qui donne une bonne explication pour en apprendre plus : [Conditionnel passé](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/conditionalperf.htm).

Comment: He would have had pity? But then why the extra avoir at the end?

Comment: The first use of "avoir" (as aurait) is with the verb devoir (as dû , the past participle). The second use is in the phrase "avoir pitié", which means "to have pity". Roughly, the sentence translates to: "He would've had to have pity" in English.

Comment: Case closed. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters Good answer and nice link, but doesn't the rough translation in your comment have one too many "haves" in it; and/or couldn't "aurait dû" perhaps be better translated here as "should've",i.e., "He should've had (or shown) pity"?

Comment: The extra "have" ("had to" in this case) is just another translation of devoir. As a native English speaker, this is the most literal way of translating the sentence to maintain the conditional perfect (conditionnel passé).

Comment: Devoir is a difficult verb to translate because there are so many ways to express its meaning in English. For example, given the phrase: "je dois", you could say: "I must", "I should", "I have to", or "I need to".